# Neo4j find first n-shortest paths

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to figure out way in neo4j to find N (const) number of path between two nodes.

With bigger graph:

```
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(
                        Traversal.expanderForTypes( Relationship.KNOWS ), 20 );
Iterable<Path> paths = finder.findAllPaths( startNode, endNode );
```

Returns way to much paths (actually I had to kill process cause it was keep on returning possible paths).

My first idea (abstract) is to find n-shortest paths like this:

1. Find shortest path with `GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(...)`
2. Look for additional paths with `GraphAlgoFactory.pathsWithLength()` increment in each iteration by 1, starting from length == path length+1 from 1.
3. Iter until you reach max length (depth) or max hit count.

But maybe I'm trying to invent wheel once again? Is there such alhorithm provided with Neo4j? I can't find any

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this algo might be something you can develop yourself and contribute to the graph-algo package, maybe as variation of allSimplePaths?